# Cannot open any d files

Tags: file, monodevelop, d

I am using Monodevelop for writing D programs, and whenever I open a file I get this [error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpaVr.png) Does anyone know about this?

Comment: What version of MonoDevelop are you using? You can try downloading the latest version which got rebranded as Xamarin.
http://xamarin.com/

Answer (score 1):

It is a common problem that happens when user has an older version of MonoDevelop (now [Xamarin Studio](http://www.xamarin.com)).

You have two solutions:

1. Get the version of Mono-D that works with the MonoDevelop version you have installed on your workstation.
2. Install the latest Xamarin Studio version, and the latest Mono-D.

How to do the #1 is little bit tricky - you have to find the plugin file, and follow the "install from file" procedure. It is explained somewhere on Mono-D blog and I believe there is a link to a page where you can see all versions...